# Javascript - create local file, and read it later, in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-filesystem

In Chrome, I can use the **FileSystem API** to create a file locally and read it later, like so:

```
// Access file system:
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, save);

// Save:
function save(localstorage) {
  localstorage.root.getFile("hello.txt", {create: true}, function(my_writer) {
    my_writer.createWriter(function(my_content) {
      var blob = new Blob(["Hello World"], {type: "text/plain"});
      my_content.write(blob);
    });
  });
}
```

Then later I can access the file using the SRC or HREF attribute of an html tag:

```
<a href="filesystem:http://www.example.com/temporary/hello.txt">Click to view</a>
```

What is the Firefox equivalent to doing the above? I need to be able to do this in Firefox including the part where I can access later using SRC or HREF. HTML5 local storage won't do the trick because that only stores text data in key value pairs, which won't give me the ability to access using SRC or HREF.

Comment: I believe you will need to use the IDBObjectStore API. Though I am not sure of the exact code needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work; I need to actually be able to access the file by its filename in an SRC or HREF attribute of an html tag. I will edit my post to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Firefox probably isn't going to be implementing  the HTML5 File-System API anytime soon [mozilla's opinion on local storage, as well as the IndexedDB](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/)

However, I think you have a couple options (mainly due to the HTML5 IndexedDB) - though there may be more options out there.

The **first option** would be to use HTML5 IndexedDB. If you want specific code/ a tutorial, please check out [this link for an intro and demo to the IndexedDB](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/)

The following is a snippet  of code from the previous link (code example credit to Robert Nymen) that I think makes your request possible - it doesn't necessarily have to be done with IndexedDB, but coupled with IndexedDB gives you the target functionality that you have with Chrome and the File-System API.

```
// Retrieve the file that was just stored
transaction.objectStore("elephants").get("image").onsuccess = function (event) {
var imgFile = event.target.result;
console.log("Got elephant!" + imgFile);

// Get window.URL object
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// Create and revoke ObjectURL
var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(imgFile);

// Set img src to ObjectURL
var imgElephant = document.getElementById("elephant");
imgElephant.setAttribute("src", imgURL);

// Revoking ObjectURL
URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
};
```

*the object store is storing a `.png` named `elephant.png`. It doesn't have to be an image, it could be a blob, text, xml or whatever else you wanted it to be. The Image gets mapped to `domain/page/indexeddb/elephant.png`*

**Second option**, you could potentially use this wrap-around [HTML5 file-system API plugin](https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js) (I say potentially, because this works over IndexedDB to give you the HTML5 File-system API functionality, and the previous example and first link shows that you can used IndexedDB to get your desired functionality)